# Getting additional tweets by an tweet's author in Twitter4J

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm trying to make a function that takes for example 5 tweets from certain hashtag then takes the users who wrote these tweets and go to their profile then takes a number of tweets from each user.

So the steps of the function are:

1. Get a number of tweets from a certain hashtag.
2. Go to each user profile who wrote in the hashtag.
3. Take number of tweets from each user profile.

How can I do this in Java?

This is the code I am working on and I want to add the previous functionalities to it.

```
Query query = new Query("#World");
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " : " + 
    status.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but should only need minor tweaks. I've commented to code to explain what it's doing.

```
// Search
final Query query = new Query("#World");
final QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

int numTweetsFromHashtag = 0;
for (Status status : result.getTweets())
{
    // If we've met our limit for the hashtag stop
    numTweetsFromHashtag++;
    if (numTweetsFromHashtag > 5) break;

    // Create a limit of tweets to get for the user
    final Paging paging = new Paging(1, 10 /*< num tweets per user*/);
    // Get that number of tweets
    final List<Status> tweets = twitter.getUserTimeline(
        status.getUser().getScreenName(), paging
    );

    // Loop over all the tweets we just got and print them
    for(final Status tweet : tweets)
    {
        System.out.println(tweet.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr. Michael. I have tried your code and it seems like there is an error with the last for loop. It says the variable "tweet" is not initialized. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Nour_em No problem. Ah yes, just a silly syntax error. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I edited Mr.Michael code a little bit since it got me an error. This is the working version of the code:

```
// Search
final Query query = new Query("#World");
final QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

int numTweetsFromHashtag = 0;
for (Status status : result.getTweets())
{
   // If we've met our limit for the hashtag stop
   numTweetsFromHashtag++;
   if (numTweetsFromHashtag > 5) break;

   // Create a limit of tweets to get for the user
   final Paging paging = new Paging(1, 10 /*< num tweets per user*/);    

   // Get that number of tweets
   final List<Status> tweets = twitter.getUserTimeline(
   status.getUser().getScreenName(), paging
   ); 

   // Loop over all the tweets we just got and print them
   for(Status tweet : tweets)
   {
       System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getName()+"--------
     "+tweet.getText()+"--------"+"\n\n");
   }

 }
```